# How to destroy all nodes and relationships and start from node 0?

Tags: neo4j

While I am able to destroy all nodes and relationships, it always starts from some node other then 0. Any idea how one can reset it back to factory state AKA 0?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `data/graph.db/` folder, or whatever folder you're using for the db, and restart.